# Map One to many with table key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have main table merchants and second table transactions:

Merchants:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Merchants {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String name;
```

Transactions:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class PaymentTransactions {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(length = 4)
    private int reference_transaction_id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "merchant_id")
    private Merchants merchants;
```

How I can configure merchant id (table key) to be reference key into table  transactions as table column `merchant_id`?

Answer (score 0):

I doubted you should use referencedColumnName property in @JoinColumn annotation and also change PaymentTransactions to List:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Merchants {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "merchant")
    List<PaymentTransactions> transactions;
}

@Entity
@Table
public class PaymentTransactions {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(length = 4)
    private int reference_transaction_id;

    @ManyToOne
    // here referencedColumnName is id column of merchant entity
    @JoinColumn(name = "merchant_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false) 
    private Merchants merchant;
}
```